# Why System.Data.Metadata Exception?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Suddenly I got bellow exception. In order to load or any Db related operation using Entity Framework. Unable to understand, what is the problem !!!!!

```
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Db.DbDatabaseMetadataExtensions.ToStoreItemCollection(DbDatabaseMetadata database)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Db.Mapping.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace..ctor(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel..ctor(DbModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.Compile()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.get_Local()
```

Please Help me. Is it any thing related to Database Skima? Unable to perform any kind of Database operation, At least 15 minutes ago , every thing running fine. I don't know, how to solve that?

Comment: What is the actual error message? I only see the call stack.

Comment: did u do a clean build. delete the stuff from ur tmp directory and try again.. or u cud even select all the entities if they are not 2 many and delete them from the model and add them back again.. because from what u said it looks like u made no changes to ur model and the entity framework tripped u..

Comment: Without showing at least the error message it is impossible to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Actual Problem, becauase of wrong **TypeName** declaration within model. It is actually differ from Db Schema.